# Touch draw in Quatz 2D/Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm trying to implement "hand draw tool".
At the moment algorythm looks like that (I don't insert any code because methods are quite big, will try to explain an idea):

**Drawing**

1. In **touchesStarted:** method I create **NSMutableArray *pointsArray**  and add point into it. Call **setNeedsDisplay:** method.
2. In **touchesMoved:** method I calculate points between last added point from the pointsArray and current point. Add all points to the pointsArray. Call **setNeedsDisplay:** method.
3. In **touchesFinished:** event I calculate points between last added point from the array and current point. Set flag **touchesWereFinished**. Call **setNeedsDisplay:**.

**Render:**

**drawRect:** method checks is **pointsArray != nil** and is there any data in it. If there is - it starts to traw circles in each point of this array. If flag **touchesWereFinished** is set - save current context to the **UIImage**, release pointsArray, set it to **nil** and reset the flag.

There are a lot disadvantages of this method:

- It is slow
- It becomes extremely slow when user touches and move finger for long time. Array becomes enormous
- "Lines" composed by circles are ugly

I would like to change my algorithm to make it bit faster and line smoother. 
In result I would like to have lines like on the picture at following URL (sorry, not enough reputation to insert an image): http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_r5VzEAUYXJ4/SrOYp8tJCPI/AAAAAAAAAMw/ZwDKXiHlhV0/s320/SketchBook+Mobile(4).png

Can you advice me, ho I can draw lines this way (smooth and slim on the edges)? I thought to draw circles with alpha gradient on the edges (to make lines smoother), but it will be extremely slowly IMHO.

Thanks for help

**Update**

I changed draw algorithm. Now every event I save **UITouch** and in the **drawRect:** method I draw path from prev. point to the current one. And dump **UIImage** from context every **drawRect:** invocation.

But I still have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to draw more smooth. I mean if I draw quite fast, I easily can see that path path is a set of straight lines. But I want to draw curves, to make path smooth. Probably Bezier curves will help but I don't understand how they can help in this.
   situation.
2. I want to start path with thiner line and finish with thiner line too. How I can do this line transform? 
   Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out because I also have the same problem and am desperate for help!!! Thanks.